# If $f(x)=x^3+1$ and $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x-1}$ then what is the domain of $(f\circ g)(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=x^3+1$ and $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x-1}$

What is the domain of $(f\circ g)(x)$

I thought that since the root function must be greater than or equal to 0 in order to be a real number, I would calculate domain by determining where the radicand is greater than or equal zero and then excluding it:

$x-1\geqslant 0 \Longrightarrow x=1$

So, I thought the domain would therefore be $[1,\infty)$

However, my textbook solutions section says the domain is actually $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need $x-1\geqslant 0$. It is $\sqrt[3]{x-1}$(which range and domain are $\mathbb R$), not $\sqrt{x-1}$(whose domain is $[1,\infty)$ and range is $[0,\infty)$).

Comment: This is correct, but it should be mentioned that taking a negative value for a cube root of a negative conflicts with the [usual](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.2#E28) choice of principal value for general powers.

Comment: As a follow up, is this true for any odd number nth root? 3, 5 7?

Comment: @Doug Fir Yeah.

Comment: @K B Dave  That's a good complement.